# From an array of objects, extract selected objects and create new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects, clone

I have an array of objects like this one:

```
var myArray = [
  {"domain":"mysite.es","id":12,"selected":false},
  {"domain":"mysite.bg","id":51,"selected":false},
  {"domain":"mysite.uk","id":41,"selected":false},
  {"domain":"mysite.bg","id":36,"selected":false},
  {"domain":"mysite.pt","id":14,"selected":false},
  {"domain":"mysite.it","id":78,"selected":false},
  {"domain":"mysite.gr","id":71,"selected":false},
  {"domain":"mysite.dr","id":73,"selected":false}
]
```

I need to create three new arrays from myArray just with selected objects. For example:

*firstArrayFromMyArray* will contain the objects with indexes 0,2 & 4,
*secondArrayFromMyArray* will contain the objects with indexes 1 & 4,
and *thirdArrayFromMyArray* will contain the objects with indexes 6 & 7

Following the above example, the output for firstArrayFromMyArray should be something like this:

```
firstArrayFromMyArray = [
  {"domain":"mysite.es","id":12,"selected":false},
  {"domain":"mysite.uk","id":41,"selected":false},
  {"domain":"mysite.pt","id":14,"selected":false}
]
```

What would be the optimal way to do it?

Comment: *What would be the optimal way to do it?* You can use a loop and process your logic. However, there is little we can do here without seeing your attempt. So please share it.

Comment: try array.filter

Comment: This is a very, very poor way of handling data. You'd have to rewrite the logic should your data order change, which defeats the purpose of automation.

Comment: You say you need the first array to be indexes 0,2,5, but in your example you show 0,2, and 4. So, which is it?

Answer (score 1):

You could take an object with the targets for each index and push the wanted object to a new outer index.

```js
var array = [{ domain: "mysite.es", id: 12, selected: false }, { domain: "mysite.bg", id: 51, selected: false }, { domain: "mysite.uk", id: 41, selected: false }, { domain: "mysite.bg", id: 36, selected: false }, { domain: "mysite.pt", id: 14, selected: false }, { domain: "mysite.it", id: 78, selected: false }, { domain: "mysite.gr", id: 71, selected: false }, { domain: "mysite.dr", id: 73, selected: false }],
    targets = { 0: 0, 2: 0, 5: 0, 1: 1, 5: 1, 6: 2, 7: 2 },
    result = array.reduce((r, o, i) => {
        (r[targets[i]] = r[targets[i]] || []).push(o);
        return r;
    }, []);
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myArray = [
  {"domain":"mysite.es","id":12,"selected":false},
  {"domain":"mysite.bg","id":51,"selected":false},
  {"domain":"mysite.uk","id":41,"selected":false},
  {"domain":"mysite.bg","id":36,"selected":false},
  {"domain":"mysite.pt","id":14,"selected":false},
  {"domain":"mysite.it","id":78,"selected":false},
  {"domain":"mysite.gr","id":71,"selected":false},
  {"domain":"mysite.dr","id":73,"selected":false}
];

function get3Arrays(myArray)
{
 let ary = [];
 ary.push([myArray[0], myArray[2], myArray[5]]);
 ary.push([myArray[1], myArray[4]]);
 ary.push([myArray[6], myArray[7]]);
 return ary;
}

let aryOfArrays = get3Arrays(myArray);

console.log('1st Array', aryOfArrays[0]);
console.log('2nd Array', aryOfArrays[1]);
console.log('3rd Array', aryOfArrays[2]);
```

Answer (score -1):

I would like to recommend to use `reduce`.

```
const {
  firstArrayFromMyArray,
  secondArrayFromMyArray,
  thirdArrayFromMyArray,
} = myArray.reduce((acc, ele, index) => {
  if (index === 0 || index === 2 || index === 5) {
    acc.firstArrayFromMyArray.push(ele);
  } else if (index === 1 || index === 4) {
    acc.secondArrayFromMyArray.push(ele);
  } else if (index === 6 || index === 7) {
    acc.thirdArrayFromMyArray.push(ele);
  }
  return acc;
}, {
  firstArrayFromMyArray: [],
  secondArrayFromMyArray: [],
  thirdArrayFromMyArray: [],
});
```